# How to get the MIN value when value is greater than (or if there's a way of calculating median in 2012)

Tags: dax

I'm trying to calculate median for a tabular cube in SSAS 2012 and MEDIAN function is not working.

I'm trying to use RANKX but having an issue finding the position.

```
Solde median :=
CALCULATE (
    'Participation'[solde_corr],
    FILTER (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            FILTER ( 'Participation', [nbr_participation] = 1 ),
            "position", RANKX ( 'Participation', 'Participation'[solde_corr] )
        ),
        [position] = XXX
    )
)
```

I need to replace the XXX in the code by (the value of position that is the greatest of all the values that are less than or equal INT(Y/2)+1 (Y beeing a COUNTROWS)

This way I'll get the MEDIAN.

If there's a way of calculating the MEDIAN in 2012 it would help too

Answer (score 0):

There's a general MEDIAN pattern in the [statistics page of DAX Patterns](https://www.daxpatterns.com/statistical-patterns/). This should work for you in SSAS 2012.

You should also look at upgrading. 1200-compatibility level is a huge upgrade in terms of DAX productivity and Tabular performance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried this as soon as I got back to work, but it doesn't seem to work for me. It doesn't return any values, it seems heavy to calculate, I just have the waiting cursor for a long time and then nothing..